# Texture mapping with OpenGL and QT - C++

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm having trouble getting my texture to map to a quad using OpenGL and Qt. I've looked at several other SO threads, but a lot of the function calls have to be used slightly differently for me to compile (Qt Verison 4.8.6). Here's my relevant code, right now all that happens is a window is displayed with a black background, but nothing else.

```
void LoadGLTextures( const char * name )
{
    QImage img;

    if(!img.load("resources/Green_Dragon.bmp")){
        std::cerr << "ERROR in loading image" << std::endl;
    }

    QImage t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(img);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
}



void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{


    qglClearColor(qtBlack.dark());
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    cameraPos = 0;
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    LoadGLTextures("resources/Green_Dragon.jpeg");

}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);  // vertex 1
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f); // vertex 2
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f); // vertex 3
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f); // vertex 4
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: (P.S. The filename you are passing to `LoadGLTextures` is being ignored, not sure if that is intentional.)

Comment: how do you know the filename is being ignored? edit: nevermind, it's because I'm not using the variable I'm passing in, duh.

Comment: I tried your advice but that hasn't fixed the problem yet, thanks for helping though.

Comment: Also I don't see you setting your projection matrix anywhere. By default GL puts a camera at (0,0,0) that faces along -Z. Either set up your camera projection, or move your quad to somewhere Z < 0 (I don't recall the default clip plane distances though). I suggest the former. Check out `gluPerspective` (apply to `GL_PROJECTION`) and `gluLookAt` (apply to `GL_MODELVIEW` to relocate camera). `QGLWidget::resizeGL()` is a good place to set up the projection matrix (because aspect ratio will change when component is resized).

Comment: *Also* (lol), unless your hardware supports *ARB_texture_non_power_of_two*, texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If your image is not a power of 2, the traditional technique is to create the smallest possible power-of-2 texture that is >= the size of the image with `glTexImage2D` (pass `NULL` data for blank), then to load your image in to a portion of it with `glTexSubImage2D` and adjust your texture coordinates accordingly (based on fraction of width/height your image takes up in the large texture). I suggest trying to draw a solid-colored quad first to make sure everything else is OK.

Comment: So I removed `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` and it works now. Not exactly sure why that is, but thank you for helping me solve this, it was your discussion of the viewport that led me to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your comment, the answer is fairly clear now, sorry that I missed it in the question comments.

You are seeing a black screen because you are enabling depth testing, but you are not clearing the depth buffer between frames. Therefore, the previous frame's depth buffer values remain in place, and the depth tests fail for all subsequent frames (note that [the default depth function is `GL_LESS`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml)).

You may leave depth testing enabled. The correct solution is to clear your depth buffer in addition to your color buffer before each render. You have:

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

But you need:

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
```

See also: [`glClear()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml)

Comment: While my answer below fixed the issue, this is the real answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Removing `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` solved this for me, in case anyone runs into a similar problem.

Comment: Oh. Duh... sorry I gave you the runaround in the question comments and missed that you weren't clearing your depth buffer (you don't need to disable depth testing, you just need to clear the depth buffer when you clear the color buffer). I hope that at least some of those comments were helpful in other ways.