# Load huge images into a QT windows and be able to zoom in and out smothly

Tags: c++, image, qt, qt5, large-files

My application need to handle huge images (>1 GB). My starting point was the image viewer example you can find in the widget folder when you install QT5. The problem with this example is that does not seem apropiate to manipulate huge images like the ones I need to handle. When zooming in and out it takes forever to update, and therefore the user experience is not good enough.

I would need something like the windows Photos app. It might take a lot of time to load the picture, but once is done, you can zoom in and out very fast. But I need to build such an application with C++ and QT, so that later I can make son calculations over the pixels.

Anyone knows any example that I can take look to build such an application, i.e, an image loader through the QT library so that I can zoom in and zoom out those images smoothly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using a QGraphicsArea?

Find some way to cut the picture up into small sections. Then, whenever the viewport of the graphics area changes, stream in only the visible squares into the graphics area.

Answer (score 0):

The way a real application handles this is a mixture of tiling and mip mapping.

Mip mapping technically is shoving lower resolution versions of an image into unused space in the image, or adjacent to it, but the idea is to cache every power of two resolution of an image.  Use the resolution one step up and interpolate pixel values.

Tiling refers to storing images not as one buffer or scanlines, but rather rectangular patches of scanlines.  This improves locality; sampling from 1000 scanline sections for a few 1000s pixels trashes your cache.

You can tweak this, rendering lower resolution versions if you are not managing the frame rate you want.  And there are probably other, fancier ways to get extreme performance.

I am unaware of a trivial way to do this in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are many solution for handling **large files** you can read file into a buffer and split it to rectangular graphics and then load and view them, and even for large files you can create a thumbnail there would be more image processing algorithm to reduce the amount of file size and keep pictures quality.

[QGraphicsview](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html) and a set of image tiles, the view handles all the scrolling and world coords for you.
Then you just have to either pre-chop the images into tiles in advance or pull a section of image data on the fly

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182781/texture-mapping-with-opengl-and-qt-c) question to find more about handling textures in **QOpenGLTexture** for large files.

Answer (score 0):

What would be needed is to have something like OpenSeadragon (https://openseadragon.github.io) in qt. I think it would be quite easy to hack my image viewer Qviv (https://github.com/dov/Qviv) to support one of the Zooming image formats. As I need something like that myself, I might actually do that. I'll update this answer if I get around to it.